# Xcode 12 Unable to use Interface Builder to add subview to scrollview

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, xcode12

Using Xcode 12 interface builder, I am unable to drag a view into a scrollview. This seems to be a very simple task that was working fine for a few years. I'm not sure what I am missing. Dragging views into other views is working perfectly though.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I have the same issue on Xcode 12.0.1. As a workaround you can start by setting up the root view of your scroll view content, select it and use the `Editor / Embed in / Scroll View` command (or alternatively, the last bottom right icon in the canvas). Then you can add to the root content view normally by drag & dropping.

Comment: Unbelievable... So much regressions in this Xcode, such a shame. If Apple applied the same policy to their own softwares than they apply to our apps, then Xcode won't have done its way to the AppStore

Answer (score 17):

I've wasted more time than I'd like to admit on this one.
You should drag directly into the drawing canvas,
not into the view hierarchy inspector.

Comment: What is wrong with Xcode? Rofl is that a bug? Thanks for the help though

Comment:  <- at least i have them all with just a shortcut whenever XCode does these to me 

Answer (score 2):

While embedding is not available i use this trick:

1. Remove *Safe area Layout guide* and *Safe area Relative margins* from parent view
2. Add your desired subview
3. Return back all safe area settings